# CCK Fieldgroup Tabs not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, cck

I installed "CCK Fieldgroup Tabs" and "Tabs" modules in my drupal site.but when in Display field options(in Content typ-> admin/content/node-type/news/display ) set view to tabs, in content page not show anything.

how to show cck fieldgroup to tabs?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your views module.I want to know whether you have installed modules like views and Quicktab module if not install the modules and try again your process.The CCK will not work without this modules.If installed means set the views module to CCk fied group and allocate the block for quick tab module.